# Filter unique values in csv and add count as a new column

Tags: javascript, python, csv, data-manipulation

I have a very large csv (50 millions records more or less) file with different columns like:

```
id, state, city, origin, destination, url, type
```

In this file, I want to check each repeated value, I mean all rows that have exactly the same columns value, remove the duplicates and then add a new column with the repeated number.

For example if I have

```
id, state, city, origin, destination, url, type
1, NY, NY, manhattan, times square, http:ny.com, taxi
1, NY, NY, manhattan, times square, http:ny.com, taxi
1, NY, NY, manhattan, times square, http:ny.com, taxi
1, NY, NY, manhattan, times square, http:ny.com, taxi
```

I want to output this

```
id, state, city, origin, destination, url, type, count
1, NY, NY, manhattan, times square, http:ny.com, taxi, 4
```

Where count is the number of times this column is repeated.
I know some javascript but not Python, however I am willing to use any tool as long as I can create a new file with the new values and columns.

Comment: use `pandas` study it little bit and you will find it ABC problem for you.

Comment: Please [show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) what you've tried

Comment: @Tserenjamts Do not blindly use pandas as soon as you see as CSV file. Processing it as text may  sometimes be simpler...

Comment: @KooiInc I haven't tried because tbh I have no idea where to start :)

Comment: @Tserenjamts thanks I will see if I can learn about pandas

Comment: Can we assume that duplicates are consecutive?

Comment: @SergeBallesta thanks for advice i thought it was easiest approach to solve the problem. And it is common so.

Comment: @KaiserSoze Google is your friend. There's [enough to find](https://realpython.com/python-csv/) on the subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no *spacing* problems, you could just process the file as text:

```
with open('input.csv') as fdin, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='\r\n') as fdout:
    header = next(fdin).strip()
    lines = {}
    for line in fd:
            line = line.strip()
            n = lines.get(line.strip(), 0)
            lines[line.strip()] = n+1
    print(header, file=fdout)
    for line, n in lines.items():
            print(line, n, file=fdout)
```

The nice point here, is that if there are a lot of duplicates, you only store the unique lines in memory.

If duplicates were consecutive, it would even be simpler and only last line would be stored in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the csv into a pandas DataFrame called df you can apply the following.

```
df.groupby(df.columns.to_list()).size()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) then, Use:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv") # read the csv file as dataframe

data = (
    df.groupby(df.columns.tolist())
    .size()
    .rename("count")
    .to_frame().reset_index()
)

data.to_csv("output.csv", index=False) # exports the dataframe as csv file.
```

This will produce a `csv` file named `output.csv` which looks like:

```
id, state, city, origin, destination, url, type,count
1, NY, NY, manhattan, times square, http:ny.com, taxi,4
....
....
```